# RegionInfo GB culture change

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I have a unit test that has always worked. the Description gets set as UK Pound Sterling (United Kingdom). It is breaking now because what is being returned is British Pound (United Kingdom). I've since updated my machine to windows 10, but can't tell if that would be the reason for this unit test to be breaking. Our build server is also now windows ten and the unit tests seem to be passing on that machine.

```
[TestMethod]
public void CheckEngland()
{
    var currencyData = new CurrencyData("GB");

    Assert.AreEqual("£", currencyData.Symbol);
    Assert.AreEqual("United Kingdom", currencyData.Country);
    Assert.AreEqual("UK Pound Sterling (United Kingdom)", currencyData.Description);
}


public CurrencyData(string countryCode2Letter)
{
    CountryCode2Letter = countryCode2Letter;

    var ri = new RegionInfo(CountryCode2Letter);
    Description = string.Format("{0} ({1})", ri.CurrencyEnglishName, ri.EnglishName);
    Country = ri.EnglishName;
    Symbol = ri.CurrencySymbol;
}
```

[image]

Comment: awesome! just what you need.   Now you need to go round adding "British Pound(United Kingdom)" to your lists :)

Comment: Wouldn't it be more robust to test against something more fixed like the ISO currency symbol rather than testing against description strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Possibility 1:** What you wanted to test is the algorithm (namely, that the `CurrencyData` object is constructed correctly from the county code).  The choice of "GB" as country code was just arbitrary.  And, for the sake of the test the actual strings are also arbitrary: it is only important that whatever the content of `ri.CurrencyEnglishName` is, will occur at the beginning of the `Descripion` string.

In this case, your test fails because of lack of isolation: The `ri` object is created with an external library that you can not control.

One of many ways to solve this is to isolate the code that interacts with external libraries from the code that holds the algorithmic core.  For example, you might create a helper function that gets as arguments the country code and a ready-made `RegionInfo` object and uses this to set up the `CurrencyData` attributes.  Then, you can test this helper function with arbitrarily created `RegionInfo` objects (under your control).

**Possibility 2:** You actually wanted to test for the original English name of the currency.  The name as delivered by the library has changed, and some other code of yours might now fail, because it depends on that string remaining the same.

In this case, you can benefit from that failed test and correct the string within the constructor, such that again "UK Pound Sterling (United Kingdom)" is delivered, and all of your existing code continues to work.

Under this assumption your tests are more of a subsystem-test nature rather than a unit-test nature.